# Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType5`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.'

Tags: c#, wpf

am trying to get the value of every cell in selected row and after i get the  way it appears this Exception

this is the exception :
'Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType5`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.'

```
        var query = (from sc in cd.SubjectTeachers
                     join s in cd.Subjects on sc.IdSubject equals s.Id
                     join t in cd.Teachers on sc.IdTeacher equals t.Id
                     join b in cd.Branches on sc.IdBranch equals b.Id

                     select new { t.NickName, s.Code, b.TypeOfBranch }).ToList();
        PlanDG.ItemsSource = query;


        DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)PlanDG.SelectedItem;

        string cellValue = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

I suppose It run but it run exception in the line of  DataRowView

Comment: Pretty obvious, you can´t convert an anonymous object to **anything** except `object`.

Comment: It means that `PlanDG.SelectedItem` is not a `DataRowView`, so you can't cast it as one. It is an anonymous type. You'll find that if you look at wherever `SelectedItem` gets set. It's not getting set to some specific type. But that's beside the point. Whatever `SelectedItem` is, it's not a `DataRowView`.

Comment: the selected Item is datagridview binded with tables ....can you please tell me what i suppose write instead of DataRowView ?

Comment: @HadySalah Please show how you populate `PlanDG`. Do you set ItemsSource? Please show all the code for how you do that, and how you create and populate the collection that goes in it. You can edit your question and add the code as text.

Comment: I did what you said

Comment: `new { t.NickName, s.Code, b.TypeOfBranch })` returns an anonymous type - like a temporary type created just to hold values in a method where it's not worth defining a whole new class. A `DataRowView` is a view of a `DataRow` - that is, you have a `DataTable` with a `DataRow` containing the values. What you're doing is something very different. Are you just getting a string and assigning it to `cellValue`? You might not even need a `DataRowView` at all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Don't forget `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

SelectedItem is going to be one of the objects in the LINQ query that you're assigning to ItemsSource. They aren't DataRowViews. They're instances of an anonymous type, and you can't cast to an anonymous type.

So your best bet is to write a little class that has the three properties you need, and use that.

```
public class DGItem {
    public String NickName { get; set; }
    public String Code { get; set; }
    public String TypeOfBranch { get; set; }
}
```

Now create those in your query instead of anonymous objects:

```
var query = (from sc in cd.SubjectTeachers
             join s in cd.Subjects on sc.IdSubject equals s.Id
             join t in cd.Teachers on sc.IdTeacher equals t.Id
             join b in cd.Branches on sc.IdBranch equals b.Id

             select new DGItem { 
                 NickName = t.NickName, 
                 Code = s.Code, 
                 TypeOfBranch = b.TypeOfBranch 
             }).ToList();

PlanDG.ItemsSource = query;
```

Now you can cast SelectedItem to a proper type, and make use of it:

```
DGItem dataRow = (DGItem)PlanDG.SelectedItem;

string cellValue = dataRow.NickName;
```